# Comparing dictionary and list of dictionaries, and returning value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm completely new to Python/programming so please bear with me if I did anything stupid or used the wrong approach to solve the problem.

What I'd like to do is to search through/compare a list of dictionaries, and returning "name" if all Keys 1-3 match, or return no match if there is none.

Is there any way to approach this problem, or if not what would be the alternative way?

Below is an example:

Database read from file, converted into list of dict

```
[{'name': 'Albus', 'Key1': 15, 'Key2': 49, 'Key3': 38},
{'name': 'Cedric', 'Key1': 31, 'Key2': 21, 'Key3': 41},
...
{'name': 'Hagrid', 'Key1': 25, 'Key2': 38, 'Key3': 45}]
```

Input read from file, converted into dict

```
{'Key1': 15, 'Key2': 49, 'Key3': 38}
```

Desired output:

```
Albus
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a `for` loop with an `if` statement where you combine multiple conditions with `and`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Python 3.10+ answer using the new [Structural Pattern Matching introduced in python 3.10](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/) and [for-else control flow](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
data = [{'name': 'Albus', 'Key1': 15, 'Key2': 49, 'Key3': 38},
{'name': 'Cedric', 'Key1': 31, 'Key2': 21, 'Key3': 41},
{'name': 'Hagrid', 'Key1': 25, 'Key2': 38, 'Key3': 45}]

to_match = {'Key1': 15, 'Key2': 49, 'Key3': 38}

for dct in data:
    match dct:
        case {'name': name, **to_match}:
            print(name)
            break
else:
    print(None)
```

Output:

```
Albus
```

Of course, for older versions this can be refactored like this:

```
for dct in data:
    name = dct['name']                        #[1]
    if {'name': name, **to_match} == dct:     #[2]
        print(name)
        break
else:
    print(None)
```

**Note**:
In Python 3.8+, line [1] can be omitted, by using [walsrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) in line [2] like this:

```
    if {'name': (name := dct['name']), **to_match} == dct:
```

Comment: Could you shed some light on the use of the double asterisk `**` in this method. I've seen its use in defining functions (for kwargs) but i dont get how it works in this context. Im assuming its similar to using `*` with lists?

Comment: @MuhdMairaj `**` is generally used as dictionary packing/unpacking operator, which is how it is used in the second part of my answer, you can find more [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). You can think of it in terms of a function. So in, `def foo(**kwargs): print(kwargs) `, if you call `foo(a=1, b=2)` the output will be `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`. Similarly, for `def foo(a, b): print(a, b)`, and call `foo(**{'a': 1, 'b': 2})`, it will be unpacked into keyword arguments.

Comment: Ahh, I see. That can be very helpful as demonstrated in your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `all()`:

```py
lst = [
    {"name": "Albus", "Key1": 15, "Key2": 49, "Key3": 38},
    {"name": "Cedric", "Key1": 31, "Key2": 21, "Key3": 41},
    {"name": "Hagrid", "Key1": 25, "Key2": 38, "Key3": 45},
]

dct = {"Key1": 15, "Key2": 49, "Key3": 38}

for d in lst:
    if all(i in d.items() for i in dct.items()):
        print(d["name"])
```

Prints:

```
Albus
```

Answer (score 1):

```
target_name = None  
for d in list_of_dicts:
  if (target_dict['Key1']==d['Key1']) and (target_dict['Key2']==d['Key2']) and (target_dict['Key3']==d['Key3']):
    target_name = d['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do a lot of these lookups, I might suggest creating another dict to act as an index.

```
>>> db = [{'name': 'Albus', 'Key1': 15, 'Key2': 49, 'Key3': 38},
... {'name': 'Cedric', 'Key1': 31, 'Key2': 21, 'Key3': 41},
... {'name': 'Hagrid', 'Key1': 25, 'Key2': 38, 'Key3': 45}]
>>> index_123 = {(d['Key1'], d['Key2'], d['Key3']): d for d in db}
>>> query = {'Key1': 15, 'Key2': 49, 'Key3': 38}
>>>
>>> index_123[tuple(query.values())]['name']
'Albus'
```